# Using references to make a function return more than one value in c++

Tags: visual-c++

I wrote a code to calculate area and circumference of a circle using references.I am getting error message as 
" unresolved external symbol "void c_decl circle" " AND
" unresolved externals"AND
"more than one instance of overloaded function"
I have given the code below

```
#include<stdafx.h>
#include<iostream>
void circle(int,float,float);
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int r;
    float a=0.0,c=0.0;
    cout<<"Enter the radius:"<<endl;
    cin>>r;
    circle(r,a,c);
    cout<<a<<"\t"<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
}
void circle(const int &i,float &j,float &k)
{
    j=3.14*i*i;
    k=2*3.14*i;
}
```

Please help.Thanks

Comment: Change `circle` forward declaration.

Comment: Forward declaration of `circle` does not match definition of `circle`.

Comment: Thanks.I corrected it.But why it is like float &a instead of just float?(I usually omit variable names and get correct output)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you wanted.

The Circle function needs to be above the main method so the compiler knows it exists when you're calling it.
The j and k parameters of the Circle function are points. Pointers are declared with the '*' . The '*' is also used to get the value from the pointer.

circle(r,&a,&c), This methods takes in the memory locations of both a and c. The memory locations are then given to the pointers. The & gets the memory location while the * gets the actual value.

Anyway it seems to work this way.

```
#include<iostream>
void circle(int,float,float);
using namespace std;
void circle( int i,float *j,float *k)
{
    float s;
    *j=3.14*i*i;
    *k=2*3.14*i;
}

int main()
{
    int r;
    float a=0.0,c=0.0;
    cout<<"Enter the radius:"<<endl;
    cin>>r;
    circle(r,&a,&c);
    cout<<a<<"\t"<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```